# How do I protect my hosts file in /etc/hosts?

Tags: mac, passwords, hosts

I'd like to prevent the active user on my computer from editing or deleting the hosts file. I'd like it so that they cannot delete it or edit it, but everything else remains as normal.

I have considered a couple of ideas -

a) I could make another user and then have the active user lose permission to edit the hosts file

b) I could password protect the `etc` folder with a separate password the main user doesn't know

Are there any other options and are either of these feasible?

Comment: Just change the permissions on the file so a non-elevated user can only read the file.  This is precisely how other operating systems handle it, and I thought, was the default behavior for MacOS.

Comment: Yeah, but the main user can still `sudo vim etc/hosts`

Comment: I got my answer - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282339/protect-hosts-file